# How do I use a proxy which contains a user and password?

Tags: networking, proxy

I wanted to set a proxy on my machine, However, the network proxy option in settings doesn't have a user:pass field, which is required to get my SOCK5 proxy working. This is my first time using Linux so I'm not very thorough with the terminal.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It's for one username

Comment: OK. Decided to add both ;-) see if the answer works for you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set this for all users on the system edit

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

and add

```
export HTTP_PROXY="{user}:{pwd}@{proxy--address}:{port}"
export HTTPS_PROXY="{user}:{pwd}@{proxy--address}:{port}"
export FTP_PROXY"{user}:{pwd}@{proxy--address}:{port}"
export NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,::1"
```

If you want it for a single user you can put those lines in

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

That method allows for a different proxy for each user. If you need a proxy for apt:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

and add

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://{user}:{pwd}@ {proxy-address}:{port}";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://{user}:{pwd}@ {proxy-address}:{port}";
```